# Generate a CREATE TABLE statement from Hive Metastore

Tags: hive, database-schema, amazon-athena, presto, hive-metastore

There's a Hadoop cluster and an accompanying Hive Metastore that describes the location and schema for various data on S3. I don't have access to the cluster, but can access the MySQL Metastore.

I want to access the data on S3 *as tables*, but given my infrequent access pattern  Amazon Athena makes much more sense that starting an EMR cluster and pointing to the Hive Metastore. The problem is that I need to `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` in Athena prior to querying the data.

I know that the Metastore has all the data I need to generate that `CREATE TABLE` query that I need to pass to Athena.

Is there any existing tool or code that can generate this query for me? Should I generate the `CREATE TABLE` statement in SQL or Python?

Comment: If you can access Metastore database, can you create another Metastore instance temporarily? Then you can use eg Presto's `SHOW CREATE TABLE` https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/show-create-table.html (or something Hive's builtin) to get the information for your `CREATE`. Would that work?

Comment: I understand this as using Presto to generate the `CREATE TABLE`. That would work but I need to deploy and configure Presto.

Comment: Kirk, I am aware this might not be the simplest option, this is just what I would probably do. Maybe someone can suggest something simpler. Re: deploy Presto, you can get it up and running using EMR or with Starburst's (ie ours) Presto on AWS (https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-aws-cloud/).

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen thanks. Ideally I'd like to just use the Presto component or module which generates that `CREATE`.